# reorganize the content of a single cell

Tags: excel

I have an issue with some dates that were imported in a format that is not recognized by excel so I'm looking  for a easy fix through vba.
The format in 31/12/2018. This doesn't seem like an unusual format so I tried to convert the text into number format and it didn't work. The only way I found that would work is to switch the value to a format like this 2018/12/31.

Basically I want to reorganize the content of the cell, but am unsure how to do so (I thought maybe the Trim function could be the one to use):

```
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer


With Workbooks("Untitled Analysis.xlsx").Sheets("Untitled Analysis")
Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngTemp = .Range("J2:J" & Lastrow)

For Each rngCell In rngTemp

TRIM(MID(J176,SEARCH("/",J176)+1,250))&"/"&LEFT(J176,SEARCH("/",J176)-1)
```

However, this returns 12/2018/31

Comment: Are you looking for something to just make a string that looks like it's the right format or are you looking for something to actually give you the date in the right format

Comment: Currently it's in text format, but I cannot convert it to a date format because it is not recognized. so by reorganizing the text to an order that is recognized as a date i will be able to convert it. Both solution you said would work, but the first one is what I had in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're data is always separated by a "/" it's probably more convenient to actually use the split function. This will just replace all the values in the cells. Full disclosure, I haven't tested this, this also changes the value into a string instead of an actual date format

```
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer


With Workbooks("Untitled Analysis.xlsx").Sheets("Untitled Analysis")
    Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngTemp = .Range("J2:J" & Lastrow)

    For Each rngCell In rngTemp
        rngCell.Value = Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(2) & "/" & Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(1) & "/" &Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(0)
    next rngCell
end With
```

EDIT This should turn it into a date value formatted properly

```
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer


With Workbooks("Untitled Analysis.xlsx").Sheets("Untitled Analysis")
    Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngTemp = .Range("J2:J" & Lastrow)

    For Each rngCell In rngTemp
        rngCell.Value = DateSerial(Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(2),Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(1),Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(0))
        rngCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
    next rngCell
end With
```

Comment: That seems like a perfect idea, however, this line of text doesnt seem to go through: 
    rngCell.Value = DateSerial(Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(3),Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(2),Split(rngCell.Value,"/")(1))

Comment: Oops, Split starts at 0, I always forget. Let me edit this

Comment: @Cunneryn try now